"Regional" Salesforce Org?
I recently learned about a concept that my company has been referring to as a "Regional" Salesforce Instance, but I can't find any documentation about this feature online and I've never heard of it before.
Supposedly, it has to do with being able to create & manage regional copies/clones of your "Core" Salesforce Production org (similarly to Sandbox management), allowing for faster rollout of Salesforce instances to new regions without having to redeploy all your customizations onto a new org.
If this is a real feature, I have lots of questions - but can't find anything helpful.
Does it only copy the "Core" Prod org once, or does it stay in constant sync as we deploy new changes to the Core org? Can you deploy specific changes to one of the regional orgs without deploying it to the Core org? etc.
Can anyone site any sources or documentation about this?
